# Why do requests appear to never leave the web browser? REACTJS / AWS-Amplify App

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

**What's the issue?**

React App with AWS Amplify@3.0.18 has eight (8) endpoints configured with API. Seven (7) of the endpoints function as expected; however, the last endpoint appears to never leave the browser. Instead, the request appears to send (as evidenced by the Network tab), but remains in a pending state until the request times out 21 seconds later.

Network Tab in Chrome:

```
(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Network Tab in Firefox

```
CORS FAILED
```

Console Error in Firefox

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows 
reading the remote resource at https://**********.execute-api.us.east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/create. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

**How is Amplify Configured?**

Configuration specific data is set via a config file. Config file is imported into the index.js file, then declared in the API endpoints array:

```
Amplify.Configure({ 
  Auth: {
  /*some auth config*/
  },
  Storage: {
  /*some storage config*/
  },
  API: {
    endpoints: [
      {
        name: "api-number-one",
        endpoint: config.apiNumberOne.URL,
        region: config.apiNumberOne.REGION
      },
      /*endpoints 2-6*/
      {
        name: "api-number-seven",
        endpoint: config.apiNumberSeven.URL,
        region: config.apiNumberSeven.REGION
      },
      {
        name: "api-that-fails",
        endpoint: config.apiThatFails.URL,
        region: config.apiThatFails.REGION
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

**Does API Register all the Endpoints?**

It appears to register all eight. A `console.log()` of the API shows each listed under the endpoints array:

[console.log() of API Endpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdDfF.png)

**How is the request being sent?**

```
  API.get("api-that-fails", "/some-path")
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

**What is expected behavior?**

The GET request is sent to API Gateway. API Gateway is the trigger for an AWS Lambda function to run. Right now, the Lambda simply sends back a dummy response - no complicated business logic at this time, until I figure out why the request doesn't hit API Gateway.

The request should return the dummy value present in the Lambda function.

**What doesn't happen?**

API Gateway never receives a request from the app; thus Lambda never runs. Cloudwatch logs on the API Gateway and Lambda confirm nothing is ever 'seen' by either.

**What odd behaviors exist?**

First, each of the other seven APIs is configured in the exact manner as the eighth; each of those functions without issue. I let amplify determine what headers to send, etc., it's worked without a problem for nearly two years now. The seventh was configured in April in the same manner as the previous six - worked without an issue.

Second, as a testing measure, I left the Lambda exposed (i.e., anything can ping it). If I take the URL to the only function that exists behind this stack, put it in the address bar of Chrome or Firefox, it immediately returns the dummy value:

```
https://**********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/the-path
```

Response:

```
{
  "TableName":"studioscale-members",
  "Item":{
    "userId":"userId",
    "transId":"2a55e900-bf9f-11ea-861f-9fe48bc133ae",
    "content":"content",
    "createdAt":1594050091920
  }
}
```

As such, this implies there isn't an issue with API Gateway or Lambda.

Lastly, it's very odd that I'm getting back a CORS error (via the more expansive explanation from Firefox), when API Gateway and Lambda never 'hear' from the app.

**What have I tried?**

(1) Made sure CORS response from Lambda was correct:

Since CORS was mentioned in Firefox, I double-triple-quadruple checked the response from Lambda to ensure it contained:

```
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
```

(2) Skip `aws-amplify` altogether.

I suspected at first maybe amplify didn't register that last endpoint and couldn't send it; however, if I replace `API.get(...)` with `axios.get(...)` it still pends, then ultimately errors.

(3) Plug the endpoint into a completely different app.

As a sanity check (since I left out any authorization for testing), I registered the endpoint inside another app and ran it.

```
/*in completely different app*/
API.get("api-that-fails", "/some-path")
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Which responds with:

```
{
  "TableName":"studioscale-members",
  "Item":{
    "userId":"userId",
    "transId":"2a55e900-bf9f-11ea-861f-9fe48bc133ae",
    "content":"content",
    "createdAt":1594050091920
  }
}
```

(4) Switch protocols from `https://` to `http://`

Didn't affect anything.

(5) Scrub `aws-amplify` docs for a limit on number of endpoints that can be registered.

Didn't find anything.

(6) Remove `endpoints` from the array (eight(8) to seven(7)) to see if there was a limit.

Didn't affect anything.

(7) Clear browser cache. Delete stack. Start from scratch.

Tried this multiple times and it did nothing different.

(8) Reference [help tip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed) in Firefox console.

I don't have an adblocker or privacy protector installed. Additionally, if I did, wouldn't that affect the other APIs?

(9) Upgrade `aws-amplify` from `v1.3.3` to `v3.0.18`

Originally using `v1.3.3` and upgraded to `v3.0.18` to see if that would resolve anything.

**So where am I at now?**

I'm convinced that AWS isn't the problem. Cloudwatch logs never register any pings to API Gateway and the Lambda never spools up. The endpoints works in another app as well, so I know the function works when it's pinged and sends back response headers that also work.

AWS Amplify appears to register the endpoint and it appears to send the request out to the wild - but no data is transferred (evidence by Network tab). So it doesn't feel like a bug with `aws-amplify`.

I feel like this is a problem with REACT maybe, since `aws-amplify` works with the other endpoints?

Comment: Yeah the CORS error in the console in a case like this is expected — but it’s misleading. Rightly the message should instead just be something like *“failed to read the remote resource at foo because the request failed without ever receiving a response”* or something like that. Anyway, from the detailed description of the question, I think you can safely rule out CORS as actually having anything at all to do with the problem.

Comment: The only guess I can offer is that maybe just maybe it could be some firewall issue within the network environment from which you’ve been testing the requests — though I admit, if that were the cause, I would think you’d been experiencing the same behavior when you try putting the URL into your browser address bar. But who knows, there could be some subtle difference that the scripted GET is running into that the browser-address-bar case doesn’t. So anyway, it might be worth also trying the request from a machine outside the network, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker. I normally dev using different networks and machines; i.e., one machine runs the code, while I use another one to view the site. I tried your suggestion, getting outside the local network by using a test environment I have set up (i.e., out on the web); but I still ran into the issue. At this point, I think I'll just start a project to move the app up to React 16.8, so I can use all the cool memoization stuff that comes with it. Hopefully, the bug will work itself out during that.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue, have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. And that isn't for lack of trying. I'm hoping it's just something to with an AWS limit on endpoints that they haven't fully documented. If you run across something, please let me know - my entire structure depends on this setup.